# configuring phpmyadmin in xampp 1.8.1

Tags: php

i just installed xampp 1.8.1 on my windows 7 pc and after that i updated the root user and gave it a password but when i click on the phpMyadmin im getting these errors

```
MySQL said: 

Cannot connect: invalid settings. 


phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

this is my config.inc.php

```
* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

what should i edit or do...thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` to the password that you just created?

Comment: @SauloSilva  yes i have